# nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "todo" in /etc/nginx/sites-available/todo.conf:29

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to deal with this problem. I try to run docker-compose up, but nginx throws this error nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "todo" in /ettell me how to solve this problemc/nginx/sites-available/todo.conf:29
redis container and db container start well. only nginx give me this error.
I have already shoveled several dozen sites, but I have not found a solution, apparently something simple, but not obvious
my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx_todo:
      build:
        context: ./nginx
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_TODO_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_TODO_PATH_CONTAINER}
        - ${NGINX_TODO_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/nginx
        - ${NGINX_TODO_SITE_PATH}:/etc/nginx/sites-available/todo.conf
        - ${NGINX_SSL_PATH}:/etc/nginx/ssl
      ports:
        - "${NGINX_TODO_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
        - "${NGINX_TODO_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
      depends_on:
        - todo
      links:
        - todo 
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend

    todo:
      build:
        context: ./web
        args:
          - INSTALL_GIT=${INSTALL_GIT}
          - INSTALL_ZIP=${INSTALL_ZIP}
          - INSTALL_NPM=${INSTALL_NPM}
          - INSTALL_CRON=${INSTALL_CRON}
          - WORK_DIR=${APP_CODE_TODO_PATH_CONTAINER}
          - NODE_VERSION=${NODE_VERSION}
      volumes:
        - ./web/cron/crontab_todo:/etc/crontab
        - ${APP_CODE_TODO_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_TODO_PATH_CONTAINER}   
      expose:
        - "9000"
      depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
      networks:
        - backend

    consumers:
      build:
        context: ./consumers
        args:
          - INSTALL_GIT=${INSTALL_GIT}
          - INSTALL_ZIP=${INSTALL_ZIP}
          - INSTALL_NPM=${INSTALL_NPM}
          - INSTALL_CRON=${INSTALL_CRON}
          - INSTALL_SUPERVISOR=${INSTALL_SUPERVISOR}
          - WORK_DIR=${APP_CODE_TODO_PATH_CONTAINER}
      volumes:
          - ./consumers/supervisor/todo.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/todo.conf 
          - ${APP_CODE_TODO_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_TODO_PATH_CONTAINER}   
      expose:
        - "9000"
      depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
      networks:
        - backend

    db:
      build:
        context: ./mysql
        args:
          - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
      environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      ports:
        - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
      networks:
        - backend

    redis:
      ##build
      build:
        context: ./redis
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/redis:/data
      ports:
        - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
      networks:
        - backend            

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}
  backend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}

volumes:
  db:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}   
  redis:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
```

and config todo.conf

```
 server {
    
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
    
        # For https
        # listen 443 ssl;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        # ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
        # ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;
    
        #server_name _;
    
        location / {
            try_files $uri @wsgi;
        }
    
        # Django media
        location /media  {
            alias /var/www/todo/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        }
    
        location /static {
            alias /var/www/todo/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        }
    
        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location @wsgi {
            uwsgi_pass  todo:9000;
            include     uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        }  
    
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    
        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
            log_not_found off;
        }
    
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    }
```

Comment: `uwsgi_pass  todo:9000;` nginx container probably can't resolve `todo`. Give it a try with the ip instead. Or attach to the container and do a nslookup to confirm.

Comment: I tried changing it to 127.0.0.1:9000 and got the same error, how do I log in to the container if it is not running?

Comment: redirect @wsgi to 404 and see if it runs then

Comment: with 404 starts normally and appears access.log

Comment: Then try to `nslookup todo` or `wget http://todo:9000` and `wget http://127.0.0.1:9000`. I suspect you are not able to read the todo application due to network reasons.

Comment: maybe it's the upstream, how do you need to register it correctly in the config?

Comment: i dont know why first time didnt work, but i tried again change todo:9000 to 127.0.0.1:9000 and it working) thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230069/discussion-between-jermah-and-iceforest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic line is `uwsgi_pass  todo:9000;`. The container is not able to resolve `todo` to an address. Replace the domain name with ip address `uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;`.

Perhaps give hostnames to your containers in the docker-compose file: `hostname: todo`.